# How to prove that something is finite

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I'm given a physical model of something. Say it's a radius of a planet:

$$R=\pi\left(\frac{n}{2\pi G}\right)^{1/2}$$
where 
$G$ is the universal gravitational constant, n - "positive constant"

If I don't have any information about n aside from the fact that it's positive, how can I make a conclusion of finiteness of R? if n goes to infinity, R would go to infinity.. am I missing something?

Comment: But $n$ is not going to infinity! $n$ is just some constant.

Comment: @TomCruise okay, so then this is sufficient then. I guess I was overthinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the things on the right hand side are finite; therefore, the left-hand side is finite.

Your confusion may stem from the similar, but distinct, notions of "arbitrarily large" and "infinite". It is true that we may set $n$ to be arbitrarily large (but finite!); however, this is different than assuming it to be infinite.

When we assume something to be arbitrarily large, we say that the relationship is true/must hold for any finite value, no matter how large we assume it to be. If we want to choose a bigger quantity, that's fine. But that quantity, too, is finite. In other words, no matter how large some finite $n$ is, $n+1$ is always bigger. This is not true for $n$ being infinite.

Comment: It is also important that the denominator of the fraction is not $0$. This may be included in your idea of "everything on the right hand side is finite" but that is not clear.

Comment: Well, yes. The denominator consists of $2$, $\pi$, and the universal gravitational constant, as acknowledged by the OP. I guess I assume that the OP knows that $G \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, but the phrasing is ambiguous. Perhaps "for every finite value of $n$ the right side is finite" would be clearer. Perhaps I am being too pedantic, but often in simple seeming questions, the problem is also simple.